# zbarimg can't scan a generated QR-Code

Tags: python, qr-code

I'm working around QR-Code, I import a QR-Code without the three big squares and I merge it with a PNG image that include the three squares to obtain a real QR-Code.

I use zbarimg to decode it but when I run i got the following error :

> "scanned 0 barcode symbols from 1 images in 0.21 seconds"
>   WARNING: barcode data was not detected in some image(s).

Here is my code :

```
background = Image.open("ImageRecup.png")
foreground = Image.open("3carre.png")

background.paste(foreground, (0, 0), foreground)
background.show()
background.save("background.png")
```

And when I read "background.png" with my phone it appears that the barcode is decoded and I got the information but not with zbarimg.

Can anyone help me ?
Thanks